# Парсер работает, но не получается записать в базу данных, в чем проблема?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, sqlite, sqlite3

Парсер работает, но не работает сохранение в бд, бд sqlite3.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('ex1.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.executescript("""CREATE TABLE news (id int auto_increment primary key, title text, post text, url text );""")
def get_html(url): 
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text
def get_total_pages(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    page = soup.find('div', class_='pagination').find_all('a',class_='pagination__num')
    total_pages = page.split('=')[1]

    return int(total_pages)

def get_page_date(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    news = soup.find('div', class_='article-list').find_all('h3', class_='article-list__item-title')
    for new in news:
        try:
            title = new.find('a',class_= 'link_nodecor').text.strip()
            print(title)
        except:
            title = ''
        try:
            url = 'https://example.ru' + new.find('a',class_= 'link_nodecor').get('href')
            print(url)
            post = requests.get(url).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(post,'lxml')
            articles = soup.find('div',class_='article').find_all('p')
            for article in articles:
                try:
                    post_text = article.text
                    print(post_text)
                except:
                    post_text = ''
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO news VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (title, post_text, url))
            cursor.commit
        except:
            url = ''

def main(): #конструктор урлов
    base_url = 'https://example.ru/articles?'
    page_part = "page="

    for i in range(1, 100):
        print(i,'итерация')
        url_gen = base_url + page_part + str(i)
        html = get_html(url_gen)
        get_page_date(html)
        print(url_gen)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно исправить запрос `INSERT` и вызывать `commit` у `connection`:

- `cursor.commit` -> `connection.commit()`
- `"INSERT INTO news VALUES (?, ?, ?)"` -> `"INSERT INTO News (title, post, url) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"`

Работающий минипример заполнения, но без парсера:

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('ex1.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.executescript("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS News (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, post TEXT, url TEXT);")

items = [
    ['Шок!', 'Нужно всего лишь втереть...', 'https://google.com'],
    ['Шок2!', 'Нужно всего втереть...', 'https://google.com2'],
    ['Шок3!', 'Нужно втереть...', 'https://google.com3'],
]

for title, post_text, url in items:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO News (title, post, url) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (title, post_text, url))

connection.commit()
```

Comment: Не помогло. В терминале все работает, а в бд ничего не выводится.

Comment: @Kirillka_Kirillov Потому что у вас ошибка `sqlite3.OperationalError: table news has 4 columns but 3 values were supplied`, но вы ее подавили в except'е

Comment: Спасибо.Все работает. Кроме одного момента: в терминале, все отображается корректно и так как надо, а вот когда дело доходит до записи, то в post_text записывается последний тег <p>. Все остальные поля записываются правильно.

Comment: @Kirillka_Kirillov, это потому что `print(post_text)` находится внутри цикла, а `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ...` после того цикла, поэтому в базу попадет значение `post_text` полученное на последней итерации цикла

Comment: Спасибо, все поправил, все работает